# CSS - Box positioning

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a layout like the image below, but the only thing I get is one row with all my boxes. I really want to keep this layout tableless, so after hours of being puzzled and researching, I'm opening my question here.

Since I can't post images, here's what I'm trying to do with CSS boxes.

```
    |  |[ ] [ ]
    |  |[ ] [ ]
```

Description: One big box at left which's the height of two little boxes. And four little boxes next to each other.

This is the CSS code of the biggest one:

```
.box {
    width:28%;
    background:#f2f5f6;
    border: 1px solid #c3d1d6;
    font-family: Lato,sans-serif;
    padding: 1.1em;
    margin: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You don't REALLY need CSS to do this, just use a table in HTML

Comment: Please don't use a table, that's terrible advice for a layout @Jonco98

Comment: @jonco98 Don't use tables for layout. That's not html5 standard. Tables are for data, not layout. Also, making that recommendation is a good way to get most non-antediluvian web developers to virulently hate you.

Comment: I didn't know it was for layout

Comment: I appreciate your attention but I would rather not use tables.

Comment: Can you provide a http://jsfiddle.net so people can play around with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can achieve this. One of the easiest is with floats.

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/964Ny/2/)

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box color"></div>
    <div class="box color"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#wrap {
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 33%;
    background: #F00;
}
.box {
    height: 50%;
    background: #FF0;
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
}
.color { background: #000; }
```

Comment: Hah! Exactly what I needed misterManSam! Great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table`.

You would wrap all those cells into a container and set the container to `display: table` and then apply `display: table-cell` to all interior elements you want to behave this way.

This is a better alternative to actual tables because it allows you to style it with CSS.  I've used this method several times in responsive designs to keep the sidebar the same height as the content.

Do keep in mind that this slightly changes the behavior of `margin` and `padding`, so you might have to play around with it for a bit.